# Why does restricting `None` fix incorrect inherents vulnerability in `batch`?

Tags: learning

In https://forum.polkadot.network/t/security-vulnerability-executing-unauthorized-xcm-messages/553 it is explained how someone could provide some incorrect inherents to the `batch` call in the utility pallet. Timestamp is used as an example of a possible incorrect inherent. I am not sure I understand why this is only possible when the origin is `None`, wouldn't the same be possible with `Signed` origin?

I would really appreciate some explanation on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention when writing inherents is to ensure that the origin is `None` doing:

```
ensure_none(origin)?;
```

At the top of the inherent. `batch` et all are forwarding the origin that called them to the inner calls. Meaning if the origin is `Signed` the inner calls will also see this `Signed` origin and as we have the `ensure_none` it will fail.